# Segmentation fault in SFML when i try to draw an sf::Text object

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm using SFML for a school project, and I'm having this problem when I try to run this code I get the error: double free or corruption (out) and the program crashes. My operating system is ubuntu.

I tried creating "text" with a `malloc`. In that case, there aren't any errors but it crashes anyway (I still get the segmentation fault). I even tried sending this code to a friend, it works for him so I think there is something wrong with my configuration or something?

```
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 320), " Text ");
    sf::Event event;
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("../arial_narrow_7.ttf");
    sf::Text text("hello", font);
    text.setCharacterSize(30);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    text.setFont(font);

    while(window.isOpen()) {
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
        window.clear();
    }
}
```

It should draw the text "hello" in red color, but as I said the program  crashes.

Comment: Where does it crash ? What's the error you're seeing ?

Comment: the error is double free or corruption (out),i'm not sure when it crashes.. i think when he tries to delete the text or the font, more specifically i get the signal SIGABRT in the file : new_allocator.h located in the c++ directory

Comment: what if you try a different font ?

Comment: i tried to use an open sans font, the error is till there

Comment: Put printf after every line to check where it crash then tell us.

Comment: ok it seems the error occurs when text is created, and when the window opens, at the start of the **window.isOpen** loop, the whole program crashes

Comment: There's nothing wrong (at first glance, I'm not super familiar with SFML) with the code posted. If there's no more code (there's presumably header files missing, at least) then I would assume it's a build configuration issue -- that is to say, is the SFML library you're compiling the same as the header files? Is the library built with the same compiler version and settings as the rest of your program, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as Bernard suggested, the problem was a external to the code itself, my version of SFML was too old, 2.3 i think, i didn't notice it because i tried to update it with the command *sudo upgrade/ sudo update* and it said that everything was up to date, so when i noticed the version in the SFML/Config.hpp file was older, I reinstalled SFML manually whit the newest files form the SFML website. Thanks everyone for your time and your helpful tips :)

Answer (score 0):

### Event loop

You should add the event processing loop in order for the window to behave properly.

According to [SFML tutorials](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php#bringing-the-window-to-life):

> A mistake that people often make is to forget the event loop, simply
>   because they don't yet care about handling events (they use real-time
>   inputs instead). Without an event loop, the window will become
>   unresponsive. It is important to note that the event loop has two
>   roles: in addition to providing events to the user, it gives the
>   window a chance to process its internal events too, which is required
>   so that it can react to move or resize user actions.

So your code should look as follows:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 320), " Text ");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("../arial_narrow_7.ttf");
    sf::Text text("hello", font);
    text.setCharacterSize(30);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    text.setFont(font);
    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You even had a unused `sf::Event` declared at the beginning of your code.

Comment: yes i know, i deleted the parts of the code that were not necessary for the draw function, i checked and the loop event doesn't influence *sf::Text*